# DatePicker In jQuery showing error

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have select a date in my datepicker but it does not takes and alert "please select a date in date format dd-mm-yyyy " when I submit.

```
function get_invoice()
{
    var client_id = $('#client_name').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{'client_id':client_id},
        url: "<?= site_url('master/get_invoice') ?>",
        success: function (data) {
            var table = document.getElementById("item-tables");
            $("#item-tables").find("tr:not(:first)").remove();
    //      $("#tbodyid").empty();
            var j=1;
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            if(dd<10){
                dd='0'+dd;
            } 
            if(mm<10){
                mm='0'+mm;
            } 
            var today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
            var date = $('.datepicker').datepicker( {autoclose: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' } );
            for (var i = 0; i < data.invoice.length; i++){
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                var balance = parseFloat(data.invoice[i].amount)-parseFloat(data.invoice[i].paid);
                row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="text" class="form-control date datepicker has Datepicker  input-sm" size="16" name="date'+j+'" id="date'+j+'" value="">';
                row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoice_id'+j+'" id="invoice_id'+j+'" value = "' + data.invoice[i].invoice_code +'" readonly>';
                j++;
            }
            $('.datepicker').datepicker( {autoclose: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' } );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show your html.

Comment: thank you for comments i fix error

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var date = $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the cause - but your datepicker dateFormat declaration is not in the same format as your "today" variable. try amending your dateFormat to be the full year (yyyy) as below

```
var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); //note this will give the full year (eg 2017)
var today = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;
var date=$('.datepicker').datepicker( {autoclose: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' } );
```

Comment: no worries - was the the full year declaration that caused the issue?